Garbage Collection Performance Counters
I'm trying to understand if I am facing an issue with garbage collection in my application and if so, what kind of an issue it is.
I'm seeing that the Gen0 and Gen1 collections are staying on the same count while the Gen2 collections is increasing (on a different scale though).
Is there a good ratio between them, I read somewhere that 100:10:1 is good, but I cannot find an official documentation that can back this up.
Mine is for example
24700:18700:1872 (which is 13:10:1) or
129,367:119,597:7678 (which is 16:15:1) later in time.
Does this indicate a problem? I read here about a problem called 'midlife'-crisis, but are those numbers really indicate this problem?
The question here is more about the general rule of thumb regarding those numbers and their ratio and the problems that may cause different ratio in each of them.
Little Info about my scenario (may be relevant to provide an answer):
I have an application that uses reads and parses information (telemetry data) from multiple devices. For each device there is two threads. One is reading raw data from serial interface as chunks of bytes every x milliseconds and the other thread takes the queued chunks of bytes and parses it.
Below is a report from perfmon with the above data.


"I'm trying to understand if I am facing an issue with garbage collection in my application and if so, what kind of an issue it is." - I would argue that to understand that you need to look at how much time your app is spending on GC first. If you have several milliseconds per minute spend in GC then arguably you should not care about  the ratios at all.

"One is reading raw data from serial interface as chunks of bytes every x milliseconds and the other thread takes the queued chunks of bytes and parses it." - sounds like you can leverage something like pooling technique (see ArrayPool<T> class) to reduce the allocations. But without seeing the actual code it is hard to tell.

@GuruStron I am using ArrayPool. How can I see the actual time my app is spending in GC? I only have the % time in GC (as attached).

It's usually < 10% so i'm guessing it is good if i'm using this counter, right?

it seems that you are spending around 5% of time in GC which in my experience is quite a lot. Also you have A LOT 2nd generation collections (the blue line), so you arguably have some problems with GC. But if you are processing A LOT of data then this can be more or less fine.

"I am using ArrayPool" - note that ArrayPool does not remove allocations completely, if it is out of "free" arrays - it will allocate a "temporary" one (which will be just tossed out on the return and then GCed). But without seeing the code -  it is hard to tell what would be recommended course of action.
